# A web based video recording widget that supports RTMP/RTSP

Tags: library, streaming, video-conferencing

I need a widget/library that enables my website to record videos from a user's camera and stream them live to my streaming server through RTMP/RTSP. Would prefer players supporting HD recording. Any suggestions would be useful.